# Почему после регистрации пользователя страница перезагружается пустой?

Tags: php, html, wordpress, woocommerce, плагин

Есть интернет-магазин построенный на wordpress+woocommerce на котором установлен плагин регистрации пользователя [WooCommerce Simple Registration](https://srd.wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce-simple-registration/). При добавлении шорткода **[woocommerce_simple_registration]** - на сайте появляется форма регистрации, где заполняем данные и по кнопке отправить - страница перезагружается пустой (в адресной строке она же остается) сайт/refistration/ 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Хотя при обновлении страницы видно, что сама регистрация прошла и на почту пришло письмо подтверждения. С чем может быть связан этот косяк и как его исправить?
вот, что выдает [debug.log](https://yadi.sk/i/xxO0qjidrmPBr)

```
<form method="post" class="register">
    <p class="form-row form-row-wide">
      <label for="reg_email">Email <span class="required">*</span></label>
      <input type="email" class="input-text" name="email" id="reg_email" value="" />
    </p>
      <p class="form-row form-row-wide">
        <label for="reg_password">Пароль <span class="required">*</span></label>
        <input type="password" class="input-text" name="password" id="reg_password" />
      </p>
    <!-- Spam Trap -->
    <div style="left: -999em; position: absolute;"><label for="trap">Анти-спам</label><input type="text" name="email_2" id="trap" tabindex="-1" /></div>
            <div class="clear"></div>
    <p class="form-row">
      <input class="input-checkbox"
           id="apply_for_vendor"  type="checkbox"
           name="apply_for_vendor" value="1"/>
      <label for="apply_for_vendor"
           class="checkbox">Желаете быть продавцом? </label>
    </p>    
    <div class="clear"></div>   
    <p class="form-row">
      <input type="hidden" id="_wpnonce" name="_wpnonce" value="4ce340f16a" /><input type="hidden" name="_wp_http_referer" value="/registration/" />            <input type="submit" class="button" name="register" value="Регистрация" />
    </p>    
  </form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Это не косяк, у вас данные передаются по POST

если измените это
    
на это

увидите данные в адрессной строке URL , 
но регистрация скорее всего работать не будет т.к у вас данные обрабатываюься через POST метод

Comment: `если измените это на это` не очень понял как предлагаете поступить - мне нужно либо на этой же странице остаться, либо на главную перейти